# index 128 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 128

Tags: python

```
for i in range(I.shape[0]):
    for j in range(I.shape[1]):
        for k in range(scale):
            for l in range(scale):
                a = k/scale
                b = l/scale
                New_img[i,j] =round( (1-a)*(1-b)*I[i,j] + (1-a)*b*I[i+1,j] + a*(1-b)*I[i,j+1] + a*b*I[i+1,j+1] )
```

index 128 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 128

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you’re trying to access the 128th element of the iterable. Python’s indexing starts from 0, so the max index for an iterable with the size of 128 is 127. The `i+1` or `j+1` is likely the problem here, however the code is a bit hard to follow with so little context.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies with `I[i+1,j] + a*(1-b)*I[i,j+1] + a*b*I[i+1,j+1]` this part of the code.

When you're doing `for i in range(I.shape[0])`, `i` will have range of `0 to I.shape[0]-1` and which is valid to iterate. But for the last element when you do `i+1` it'll try to access `I.shape[0]`th index of `I`'s axis 0 which isn't there. Same goes for axis 1.

**Solution**: You can iterate on `range(I.shape[0]-1)` and `I.shape[1]-1` for `i` and `j` respectievly.